# Popup from a link in EXTJS

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs4

I have the following piece of EXTJS code in which I have to display a hyperlink and when the user clicks, it has to open up a popup window which is another ext js view that is already created.

```
{
    xtype: 'label',
    width: 170,
    border: false,
    html: '<a href="popup.js">ACCOUNTS-3</a>'
}
```

The above piece of code doesn't work because it goes to the URL curentURL/popup.js which is invalid.

```
Ext.define('MyappDesktop.view.taso.TransactionListPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.GridPanel',
alias: 'widget.transactionList',

title: 'Transactions',

initComponent: function() {
    this.store = 'Transactions';
    this.columns = [
        { header: 'AMOUNT', dataIndex: 'transaction_amt', flex: 0 },
        { header: 'POSTING STATUS', dataIndex: 'posting_sta_ind', flex: 0 },
        { header: 'ITEM DESCRIPTION', dataIndex: 'item_desc', flex: 0 },
        { header: 'SERIAL NUMBER', dataIndex: 'serial_no', flex: 0 },
        { header: 'TRANSACTION CODE', dataIndex: 'transaction_code', flex: 0 },
        { header: 'RETURNABLE', dataIndex: 'is_returnable', flex: 0 },
        { header: 'VALUE DATE', dataIndex: 'value_date', flex: 0 },
        { header: 'BOOKING DATE', dataIndex: 'booking_date', flex: 0 }
    ];
    this.viewConfig = {
        stripeRows: true
    };

    this.dockedItems = [{
        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
        store: 'Transactions',
        dock: 'bottom',
        displayInfo: true
    }];

    this.callParent(arguments);
}});
```

Comment: If the other view has already been created, then you should just show the instance of the view that has already been (by either adding it to a window or other panel, or by showing it directly). If you open a new window, your "already created" view will no longer exist and will have to be re-created as the new window will reload all of your code.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If I am adding the other view in a window, how should I call the window from the hyperlink? That is what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Since your other view is already created, the best approach is probably to add a click event listener to the label's element, and use that event's handler to show the view.

```
 { 
    xtype: 'label',
    text: 'ACCOUNTS-3',
    width: 170,
    border: false, 
    listeners: { 
        element: 'el', 
        click: function () { 
            // get instance of other view and display it
        } 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Can you show how to use the instance of the other view?

Comment: Sure, but you'll have to provide details about your view's definition.

Comment: Added the view details!